# I need help regarding hearing high frequencies!

Tags: sound

I am sorry if I am not posting this in the right place. I am a 27 years old guy and I have a very bad ear at hearing high frequencies, I only figure out this today after doing more than 20 hearing tests (diff websites, videos, apps ect..) The result is I couldn't hear anything above 8khz on all these tests with regular average volume. Eventually what I did is, generating a pure sine wave then play it in whole human audio spectrum (20hz--20khz) I tried this with both headphones/earphones and speakers. if I turn up the volume 100% the highest frequency I can hear is 13khz, I could hear absolutely nothing after 13khz. I don't have any hearing problem or any difficulty hearing quiet noises (except these high frequencies) and I am also a musician and I have a good relative pitch, I can sing any note perfectly in tune if you give me a reference note and I am able to recognize any melodic/harmonic interval with no effort. Also there's one thing I didn't understand, there was one videos on youtube I tried, it was a sine-wave raising the pitch gradually from 20hz to 20khz, on this video I stopped hearing at 13khz on 100% volume but at 15Khz I started hearing again (something that sounded much lower than what the frequency must be, I would say) the sound is like a tape drop effect or like when you do a drop with the guitar whammy bar, which is very weird espeially that the audio is only a sine-wave which means there's only one harmonic which is the fundamental, so I converted this youtube video and played it on my DAW and opened a detailed graph to visualize what is happening. I saw nothing except a normal sinewave increasing the pitch! still hearing this weird thing after 13khz!  is this normal ? Do I have some hearing problems ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a medical question.

Comment: The 'whammy bar' effect would be aliasing of some sort, interference between the audio sample frequency as transmitted & the frequency of the sound itself. Imported at full resolution that would disappear. The rest is a medical issue. Lots of musos lose their top end, if they've been subjected to loud noise [gigs] a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson we are not audiologists nor is this an audiology forum. Nobody will give you an answer to this question that you should accept. Nor should you be posting for answers to medical questions on the internet expecting to be given answers by randoms.

Go and see an audiologist.